# Hide initial buffer list in Emacs' iswitchb-mode

Tags: emacs, switch, buffer

How can I configure iswitchb-mode so that it does not display the list of all (matching) buffers until I hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> for the first time?

Comment: That's what iswitchb is about that you don't have to type extra keys to show the matches. It pays off for such a frequent operation. Why is it a problem if it shows the matching buffers?

Comment: @Tom "Problem" may be too big a word, but when I have many buffers open at the same time, the list is so long that displaying it becomes kind of pointless. The main reason I'm using iswitchb is not to save a keystroke, but because it allows to match *any* substring in a buffer-name, not only at the beginning of the buffer-name, as `switch-to-buffer` does. As an alternative to waiting for my TAB, I could also deal with a "maximum buffer count" setting, in the sense that it only displays the matching buffer list once I've discriminated it down to N alternatives.